# Oibaf install disables wifi

Tags: graphics, intel-graphics, intel, thinkpad

I've installed the oibaf graphics drivers https://launchpad.net/~oibaf/+archive/ubuntu/graphics-drivers on ubuntu 14.04 lte, with latest kernel 4.2.3.

I have a thinkpad x1 gen3 with intel 5500 graphics card.

After the install the graphic performance is greatly improved but the wifi does not work anymore.

Any ideas on how to get this to work?

Answer (score 1):

So the problem was that the oibaf install removes the iwlwifi drivers

Output of `ls -al /lib/firmware/*iwl*7265*` before install:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  736844 oct 16 15:52 /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-7265-10.ucode
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  880604 oct 16 15:52 /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-7265-12.ucode
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  885224 oct 16 15:52 /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-7265-13.ucode
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  690452 oct 16 15:52 /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-7265-8.ucode
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  691960 oct 16 15:52 /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-7265-9.ucode
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  740436 oct 16 15:52 /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-7265D-10.ucode
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1002800 oct 16 15:52 /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-7265D-12.ucode
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1008692 oct 16 15:52 /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-7265D-13.ucode
```

And the same command after install:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  690452 oct 16 15:52 /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-7265-8.ucode
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  691960 oct 16 15:52 /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-7265-9.ucode
```

My was to simply backup and copy the files after the update.

I am preatty sure someone should know about this but I don't know where to post this finding, please comment with suggestions.